# @PersistenceContext is null Glassfish 4

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, cdi

I am creating a J2EE WebAPP with JSF Glassfish 4 and Eclipse

The weird thing is, I am doing the same things in two different applications anwhat works in one, leads to a NullPointerException in the other.

My ManagedBean is:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "showEntriesBean", eager = true)
@RequestScoped
public class ShowEntriesBean {
    @EJB
    EntryEAO eao;
    public List<Entry> getEntries() {
        return eao.getEntries();
    }
```

EntriesEAO is:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EntryEAO {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "LBBBankingWeb")
EntityManager em;
public final List<Entry> getEntries() {
            // This Line is leading to the NullPointerException an em is null
    final TypedQuery<Entry> query = em.createQuery("select r from " + Entry.class.getName() + " r order by r.valutadate", Entry.class);
    List<Entry> entries = query.getResultList();
    return entries;
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="LBBBankingWeb">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/lbb</jta-data-source>
        <class>de.docfaust.lbbweb.entity.Entry</class>
        <class>de.docfaust.lbbweb.entity.Rule</class>
        <class>de.docfaust.lbbweb.entity.Blockedrecipient</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I put the getEntries() code directly in the ManagedBean it works. The configuration of the persistence thus seems to be correct, so I think it's an injection problem.

I have read the many questions here dealing with @PersistenceContext and CDI and some are about the right configuration of beans.xml.

I don't actually have a beans.xml but it's interesting that

1. in my other Webapp I don't have one either and it works;
2. other injections like the one of  the EntryEAO do work.

Dependencies of POM

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Is that `eao` object getting injected or created in the `ShowEntriesBean` in code you haven't included?

Comment: This may be a problem caused by the packaged dependencies. Maybe you can add the `pom.xml` files of the two projects. PS: Why the `@LocalBean`? (Anyway it shouldn't make a difference...)

Comment: @chrylis The eao (EntriesEAO) is injected in the ManagedBean ShowEntriesBean at the beginning

Comment: @unwichtich: pom added, it's only ONE Project. The LocalBean was just a try to solve not a real need

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer:

It was in the EAO

```
public final List<Entry> getEntries() {
    final TypedQuery<Entry> query = em.createQuery("select r from " + Entry.class.getName() + " r order by r.valutadate", Entry.class);
    List<Entry> entries = query.getResultList();
    return entries;
}
```

With removing the "final" modifier everything worked fine

```
public List<Entry> getEntries() {
    TypedQuery<Entry> query = em.createQuery("select r from " + Entry.class.getName() + " r order by r.valutadate", Entry.class);
    List<Entry> entries = query.getResultList();
    return entries;
}
```